# Tomcat and Browser to Openfire Authentication scheme

Tags: javascript, tomcat, authentication, cookies, xmpp

We are developing a web application that uses strophe.js to communicate with an openfire server for XMPP chat. The web application is hosted on tomcat and both tomcat and openfire reside on the same server. Strophe.js is using BOSH (essentially http long-polling) as a communication mechanism between the client and the openfire.

Our tomcat instance authenticates (form-based) using a users table in our database. We've configured our openfire instance to read out of the same table. That way mobile apps can directly connect to our chat server using the user's credentials

We also have apache running as a reverse proxy. This might be TMI for the problem at hand, but more information can't hurt. The url schemes look like the following:

`http://myserver/web`  Our web interface. Goes to `http://myserver:8080/`

`http://myserver/chat` Forwards to the openfire BOSH url (what strophe.js connects to). Goes to `http://myserver:7070/http-bind` (openfire bosh endpoint)

The problem I'm trying to figure out is how to log in to our openfire server from the browser. For example, if the user goes to the `login.jsp` site and enters their credentials, the server will forward that user to `index.jsp`. The strophe.js connection will try to connect to the chat server (`/chat`), but at that point, the username and password is no longer available to the javascript code.

I need to figure out how to securely authenticate the user in the web browser with the openfire server AFTER authentication has occurred. I've looked around for some examples, but there's not much information out there (or rather, I don't know what to look for).

**Some Possible Solutions**

1.) The first strategy I tried was creating an AuthProvider implementation in openfire that can take the browser's cookie as the password, make an HTTP request to tomcat with that cookie, and if succeeds deem that user as authenticated. This worked at first, but when deploying I found that I needed to configure tomcat to allow the `document.cookie` to be populated with the JSESSIONID. After reading a bit about this, it seems that using cookies is not recommended from a security standpoint. Jeff Atwood has an post [Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) that discusses the security issues stemming from cookies accessible to javascript. Although I am not completely opposed to using cookies, is there a better way?

2.) A solution I have also thought of (haven't implemented yet) was providing a REST endpoint to create tokens that the user can fetch once they are logged in and use as passwords for the openfire server. Seems a little better, but I'll need to create a new table, manage their expiration, etc.

If anyone has tackled this problem, please let me know. It would be greatly appreciated.